# Compile a JDK 8 project + a JDK 9 "module-info.java" in Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, javac, java-9, java-module

I'm working on a Java library targeting JDK 8, and I'm building it in Gradle 5 using OpenJDK 11. In order to target JDK 8, I'm javac's [`--release`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/javac.html#GUID-AEEC9F07-CB49-4E96-8BC7-BCC2C7F725C9__GUID-D343F6B4-3FDD-43A8-AD24-43DD70214471) option.

However, I'd also like my library to be JPMS-compatible. In other words:

- I'd like to provide a `module-info.class` compiled with `--release 9` (option 3 in [Stephen Colebourne's scale](https://blog.joda.org/2018/03/jpms-negative-benefits.html)),
- while all the rest is compiled with `--release 8`.

## MCVE

**build.gradle**:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.javamodularity.moduleplugin' version '1.4.1' // *
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.6'
}

compileJava.options.compilerArgs.addAll(['--release', '9']) // **
```

* [`org.javamodularity.moduleplugin`](https://github.com/java9-modularity/gradle-modules-plugin) sets `--module-path` for `compileJava`

** there's no Gradle DSL for `--release` yet: [#2510](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/2510)

**src/main/java/module-info.java**:

```java
module pl.tlinkowski.sample {
  requires lombok;
  exports pl.tlinkowski.sample;
}
```

**src/main/java/pl/tlinkowski/sample/Sample.java**:

```java
package pl.tlinkowski.sample;

@lombok.Value
public class Sample {
  int sample;
}
```

This MCVE compiles, but all the classes (instead of only `module-info.class`) are in JDK 9 class format ([v.53](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170832/list-of-java-class-file-format-major-version-numbers)).

## Other build tools

What I want to do is certainly possible in:

1. Maven

   - E.g [ThreeTen-Extra](https://github.com/ThreeTen/threeten-extra/blob/ba8287341f347a60ad96ad6a3f3e1055ab1a7278/pom.xml#L656) (their approach boils down to: first compile everything with `--release 9`, and then compile everything except `module-info.java` with `--release 8`).
2. Ant

   - E.g. [Lombok](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/blob/master/build.xml#L251) (their approach boils down to: have `module-info.java` in a separate "source set" - main source set is compiled with `--release 8`, and "module info" source set is compiled with `--release 9`).

## What I tried

I liked Lombok's approach, so I manipulated the source sets in `build.gradle` as follows:

```
sourceSets {
    main { // all but module-info
        java {
            exclude 'module-info.java'
        }
    }
    mainModuleInfo { // module-info only
        java {
            srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
            outputDir = file("$buildDir/classes/java/main")
            include 'module-info.java'
        }
    }
}
```

Then, I configured a task dependency and added proper `--release` options to both compilation tasks:

```
classes.dependsOn mainModuleInfoClasses

compileJava.options.compilerArgs.addAll(['--release', '8'])
compileMainModuleInfoJava.options.compilerArgs.addAll(['--release', '9'])
```

If I compile now, I get:

> error: package lombok does not exist

So I still *don't know* how to instruct `org.javamodularity.moduleplugin` to:

- not use `--module-path` for `main`
- set proper `--module-path` for `mainModuleInfo`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gradle: Building a modularized library that is compatible with Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48928723/gradle-building-a-modularized-library-that-is-compatible-with-java-8)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*EDIT:* This functionality is now supported by *Gradle Modules Plugin* since version [1.5.0](https://github.com/java9-modularity/gradle-modules-plugin/releases/tag/v1.5.0).

Here's a working `build.gradle` snippet:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.javamodularity.moduleplugin' version '1.5.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.6'
}

modularity.mixedJavaRelease 8
```

---

OK, I managed to get this working by:

1. disabling `org.javamodularity.moduleplugin`
2. removing the custom source set (it wasn't necessary)
3. adding a custom `compileModuleInfoJava` task and setting its `--module-path` to the classpath of the `compileJava` task (inspired by [this Gradle manual](https://guides.gradle.org/building-java-9-modules/#modify_the_code_compilejava_code_task_to_produce_a_module))

Here's the full source code of `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.6'
}

compileJava {
    exclude 'module-info.java'

    options.compilerArgs = ['--release', '8']
}

task compileModuleInfoJava(type: JavaCompile) {
    classpath = files() // empty
    source = 'src/main/java/module-info.java'
    destinationDir = compileJava.destinationDir // same dir to see classes compiled by compileJava

    doFirst {
        options.compilerArgs = [
                '--release', '9',
                '--module-path', compileJava.classpath.asPath,
        ]
    }
}

compileModuleInfoJava.dependsOn compileJava
classes.dependsOn compileModuleInfoJava
```

Notes:

- it compiles
- I verified that `module-info.class` is in JDK 9 format (8th byte is `0x35` → [v.53](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file#General_layout)), while other classes are in JDK 8 format (8th byte is `0x34` → [v.52](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file#General_layout))
- however, disabling `org.javamodularity.moduleplugin` is unsatisfactory, because it means that tests will no longer run on module path, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I have developed a Gradle plugin for this: https://github.com/Glavo/module-info-compiler

I have tried Gradle Modules Plugin, but there are still some troublesome problems, so I developed this plugin, a compiler specifically used to compile `module-info.java`.

It is not implemented by calling javac. It is a complete compiler that can run above Java 8. It recognizes the syntax of `module-info.java` and generates the corresponding `module-info.class` file according to it.

It only checks the grammar, and does not actually check those packages, classes or modules, so it can work without configuration of any module path.

This Gradle plugin has processed everything for you. For a Java 8 project containing `module-info.java`, you only need to do this:

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("java")
    id("org.glavo.compile-module-info-plugin") version "2.0"
}

tasks.compileJava {
    options.release.set(8)
}
```