# How to setup a IntelliJ/Gradle project with targetCompatibility=1.8, and sourceCompatibility=1.9 or higher?

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I have an [open-source Java library project](https://github.com/BetterCloud/vault-java-driver), for which I would like the built artifact to maintain compatibility with Java 8 as long as possible.

I recently received a [pull request](https://github.com/BetterCloud/vault-java-driver/pull/165), to add a `module-info.java` file and setup Gradle for Java 9+ support.  Between that PR and the [Gradle documentation](https://guides.gradle.org/building-java-9-modules/), I have re-worked the relevant portion of `build.gradle` to look like this:

```groovy
sourceCompatibility = 1.9
targetCompatibility = 1.8

ext.moduleName = 'vault.java.driver'
compileJava {
    inputs.property("moduleName", moduleName)
    doFirst {
        options.compilerArgs = [
                '--module-path', classpath.asPath,
        ]
        classpath = files()
    }
}

compileTestJava {
    inputs.property("moduleName", moduleName)
    doFirst {
        options.compilerArgs = [
                '--module-path', classpath.asPath,
                '--add-modules', 'junit',
                '--add-reads', "$moduleName=junit",
                '--patch-module', "$moduleName=" + files(sourceSets.test.java.srcDirs).asPath,
        ]
        classpath = files()
    }
}
```

This is great, but I'm noticing some serious confusion between Gradle and IntelliJ.

When I import the project in IntelliJ, it does so cleanly, and the project structure clearly shows "Language Level" 9.  IntelliJ seems to understand my `build.gradle` just fine, as it changes the language level to 8 when I temporarily set `sourceCompatibility=1.8` and refresh.

However, when I click "Build Project" from the "Build" pull-down menu, I get the error:

```
Error:(1, 1) java: modules are not supported in -source 8
  (use -source 9 or higher to enable modules)
```

Meanwhile, when I try to bypass IntelliJ and run `./gradlew build` from the command-line, Gradle doesn't seem to understand my `sourceCompatibility` or `targetCompatability` settings:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> invalid source release: 1.9
```

I'm really confused.  How does on create a `build.gradle` file, which both:

- allows for Java 9+,
- while still maintaining built artifact compatibility with Java 8, and
- makes both Gradle and IntelliJ happy?

Comment: NOTE:  Upgrading my Gradle wrapper from 4.10 to 5.4 had no effect.

Comment: You might be able to use [the `--release`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43102787/what-is-the-release-flag-in-the-java-9-compiler) flag. [This Gradle blog](https://blog.gradle.org/mrjars) may also be helpful (haven't read it thoroughly), which seems to have been written in response to [JEP 238](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/238).

Comment: `java: modules are not supported in -source 8` You can not use module-info when compiling against 1.8 source, see https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8206896 Check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55100737/compile-a-jdk-8-project-a-jdk-9-module-info-java-in-gradle Enable Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | Runner | **Delegate IDE build/run actions to Gradle** option to get identical results in IDE and Gradle.

Comment: @Andrey:  Hmm... but I am setting "sourceCompatability" to 1.9 for this very reason.  Only the "targetCompatability" is set for 1.8 (because I want the built artifact to maintain Java 8 backwards compatibility).  Why would Gradle or IntelliJ reference "targetCompatability" rather than "sourceCompatability" for this?