# how to use gradle build java library with module system?

Tags: java, gradle, java-9, java-platform-module-system

how to use gradle build java library with module system ?

how to use gradle to do this:

1. build a jar with module-info.java
2. the jar can be use to both java8 and java9

Comment: merge that question into one, how to build multi-release jars using Gradle? (I think that might have already been answered.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gradle: Building a modularized library that is compatible with Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48928723/gradle-building-a-modularized-library-that-is-compatible-with-java-8)